# How should I replace a clogged drain tile under my gravel driveway?

Tags: water, concrete, drainage, french-drain

I have a drainage pipe running around the house. One segment of it was buried right next to the garage threshold, it got completely clogged. The pipe eventually goes across the front lawn and into the ditch away.

I undug and took out the pipe:

[image: trench1]
[image: trench2]
[image: trench3]

Now, I think I have 3 options:

1. Install new piece of flexible corrugated pipe, possibly in a cloth sleeve to minimise clogging. i.e. connect outlets on the left and right of garage entrance.
2. Install a piece of PVC solid pipe
3. Install some sort of storm drain channel with grate ([example](https://images.homedepot.ca/productimages/p_1001592555.jpg?product-images=l)) at the threshold

I understand that the drain channel needs to be laid in concrete and stay solid, however I'm not sure if concrete will last well, since my driveway has no asphalt; it is gravel.

If I just bury a pipe (corrugated one or PVC for example), how can I ensure that cars passing over threshold don't crush the buried pipe over time?

What would be the most adequate option?

Comment: @isherwood, it a drainage pipe, running around the house, one segment (subject of this topic) of it is running along the garage door. The pipe eventually goes across the front lawn and into the ditch away.

Comment: Don't tell me down here, tell _us_ up there in your question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need water scavenging at the driveway location...

- Lay rigid support over the pipe trench, such as a steel plate.
- Go with schedule 80 PVC, but put a few holes in it and wrap it with landscape fabric.
- Simply replace it and pour yourself an apron slab. It might be nice to have and would keep gravel out of the garage better.

If not, just replace that segment with rigid pipe. You could also do a combination of both, with a drain segment in the center where it's less likely to be crushed.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, @isherwood, I had to mention that on Picture3 is the drainage pipe outlet, there is the same on the right-hand side of the garage entrance. So, connecting these two outlets with 80  PVC pipe (drill holes on the bottom, and wrap in landscape fabric), and then pouring concrete over it is also an option? This concrete apron (as you said) should be at the same level as garage floor, i.e. same grade, correct?

Comment: Yes and yes. An apron is a garage slab extension and usually has some outward slope.

Comment: Is clear stone required on the bottom of trench?

Comment: I'm not sure what "clear stone" is, but nothing's _required_. Use the best cost-effective drainage substrate available.

Comment: as to my knowledge clear stone serves well as draining material, its shape is such that it creates space between each angular stone to allow liquid to drain through.

Comment: If it's what I know as "washed rock" or "river rock", sure. Spot on.